# projecting all columns of a nested relation in pig

Tags: apache-pig

I have a relation MY_REL that is the result of a join of X and Y:

```
MY_REL = {X::x1,X::x2,Y::y1,Y::y2}
```

And I tried to do

```
Bla =       foreach MY_REL generate X;
```

Pig vomited:

```
ERROR 1000: Error during parsing. Scalars can be only used with projections
```

I tried X::* and it throws: invalid alias X.

The ugly workaround: I switched to explicitly writing all column names:

```
Bla =       foreach MY_REL generate X::x1, X::x2;
```

Is there a nice way to generate all X's columns?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using `JOIN`, use [`COGROUP`](http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.9.2/basic.html#COGROUP). `COGROUP` will create a relation that looks like `{X : {x1, x2}, Y : {y1, y2}}`. Therefore, you can do:

```
foreach MY_REL GENERATE FLATTEN(X);
```

Note that it is a bag in there, so you want to `flatten` it.

Comment: creative thought! however, what created this relation is a LEFT join, so I guess it can't be replaced by a COGROUP, right?

Comment: You can replace it with a `COGROUP` if you do a `FILTER` afterwards that filters where `X` has a size greater than 0.

Comment: worked like a charm. further explanation for newbies why this works: when PIG does any `JOIN`/`COGROUP`, it does a map-reduce grouping all rows from file A and file B with join-key=gaga. It doesn't mind if there are 2 such rows from file A and 3 from B, or 0 rows from A, or 0 from B. This is what SQL people will call `FULL OUTER JOIN`. If we ask for a `COGROUP`, we're done. If we ask for a `JOIN`, PIG generously filters out the groups for which one of the files has 0 rows.

Answer (score 1):

If your columns before the JOIN all have a different name, you can just use them as is later:

```
Bla =       foreach MY_REL generate x1 + y1, x2 + y2;
```

If only one conflict you need to use the original prefix relation

```
Bla =       foreach MY_REL generate x1, x2, y1, Y:y1 AS y2;
```

An with the new Pig range [PIG-1693](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-1693)

```
Bla =       foreach MY_REL generate ..$2, $3 AS y2;
```

And there is also some talks in [PIG-2511](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/PIG-2511)

Comment: ok - no need to fully-qualify the columns with the relation name, but still I have to explicitly name them all, right?

Comment: No if you use the range operator '..' (came in Pig 0.9), but if not yes you need to name in the GENERATE all the columns you want to keep for later. I personally either pick names with no conflicts or just rename all the columns in my next FOREACH.